# List<string> get item that starts with Name= using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

How can i retrieve from a `List<string>` the item(value) that starts with `Name=`

If the list contains the values:

```
Name=Jhon Smith
Age=20
Location=CityName
```

I want to get the value `Jhon Smith`.

I do know how to traditionally loop through the list using foreach and have a condition if value starts with `Name=` ... but I'm not that good with LINQ.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will throw an exception if there is no such element in the collection.
You can use [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) and check if you get null or an element to check 
whether there was a match or not.

```
list.First(x => x.StartsWith("Name=")).Substring(5)
```

This won't throw an exception:

```
var prefix = "Name=";
var elem = list.FirstOrDefault(item => item.StartsWith(prefix));
if (elem != null) {
    return elem.Substring(prefix.Length)
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Well, of course. I just thought I didn't need to write the whole program for him ;) - There's always some error checking and -handling to add :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Single`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535118.aspx) or [`SingleOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault.aspx) like this:

```
var result = list.Single(s => s.StartsWith("Name=")).Substring(5);
```

or

```
string result = string.Empty;
var element = list.SingleOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith("Name="));

if (element == null)
{
    //"Name=" not present, throw an exception
}

result = element.Substring(5);
```

or similarly with [`First`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx), or [`FirstOrDefault`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx) depending on what you exactly want.

There was another interesting answer by the user [canon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/621962/canon), but was deleted (I don't know why):

```
var result = list
              .Where(x => x.StartsWith("Name="))
              .Select(x => x.Substring(5))
              .FirstOrDefault();
```

Its advantage is that it won't throw regardless of the input data.

Comment: @user2818430 I've integrated a deleted answer with mine also.

Comment: Doesn't `singleordefault` throw an exception if more than one item matches, making `firstordefault` the safer non exception answer?

Answer (score 1):

```
String match = list.FirstOrDefault( str => str.IndexOf("Name=", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) > -1 );
return match.Substring("Name=".Length);
```

Comment: This will throw an exception if the "Name=" field is not present.

Comment: That doesn't actually filter on where the string "starts with" `Name=` but rather if it Contains `Name=`. Change it to `== 0`.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly modernized and updated version that:

- uses C# indexer
- does not use the magic value of *5* (which is `"Name=".Length`):

```cs
var list = new List<string> { "Name=Jhon Smith", "Age=20", "Location=CityName" };

const string namePrefix = "Name=";
string? name = list.FirstOrDefault(s => s.StartsWith(namePrefix));
name = name?[namePrefix.Length..]; // Jhon Smith
```