# Find out if string list items startswith another item from another list

Tags: c#, list, loops, startswith

I'd like to loop over a string list, and find out if the items from this list start with one of the item from another list.

So I have something like:

```
List<string> firstList = new List<string>();
firstList.Add("txt random");
firstList.Add("text ok");
List<string> keyWords = new List<string>();
keyWords.Add("txt");
keyWords.Add("Text");
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19146273/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do that using a couple simple for each loops.

```
foreach (var t in firstList) {
    foreach (var u in keyWords) {
        if (t.StartsWith(u) {
            // Do something here.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That was so simple that I'm feeling bad. Thank you for your answer :)

Answer (score 4):

If you just want a list and you'd rather not use query expressions (I don't like them myself; they just don't look like real code to me)

```
var matches = firstList.Where(fl => keyWords.Any(kw => fl.StartsWith(kw)));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
from item in firstList
from word in keyWords
where item.StartsWith(word)
select item
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one it is working fine.

```
var result = firstList.Where(x => keyWords.Any(y => x.StartsWith(y)));
```