# To find index of substring in a list of string VB.net

Tags: string, vb.net, list

hi i have a String List XML_Dump
i want to find the index of the row in a list which contains or starts with "MRBTS-486215"
I tried this but not getting correct input Please help

If Not XML_Dump.Contains("MRBTS-486215") Then
            index_Range1 = index_Range1 + 1
        End If

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22988513/find-out-if-string-list-items-startswith-another-item-from-another-list

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the value you want:

```
 Dim XML_Dump As New List(Of String)
 XML_Dump.Add("1233")
 XML_Dump.Add("2132132MRBTS-4862152343")
 Dim index As Integer = XML_Dump.FindIndex(Function(x As String) x.Contains("MRBTS-486215")) ' This Returns a 1
```

Reference: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb(v=vs.110).aspx